Python pola.rs OOM on a 30Gb file
I need to aggregate raw time-series data into OHLC with 1m granularity. I built code with python-polars which returns this plan:
 SELECT [col("parsed_timestamp"), col("label1"), col("open"), col("high"), col("low"), col("close")] FROM
  AGGREGATE
        [
           col("price").first().alias("open"), 
           col("price").max().alias("high"), 
           col("price").min().alias("low"), 
           col("price").last().alias("close")
        ] BY [col("label1")]
FROM
     WITH_COLUMNS:
     [col("timestamp").strict_cast(Datetime(Microseconds, None)).alias("parsed_timestamp")]
      Csv SCAN [ticker.csv]
      PROJECT */11 COLUMNS

I use scan_csv and collect(streaming=True). Also, I call   .group_by_dynamic("parsed_timestamp", every="1m", group_by=["label1"]) (which is not seen in plan for some reason).
However this code still uses 30Gb of memory when aggregating 30Gb file. Is there any optimizations I can do? Data is sorted by timestamp in ascending order.
I made a simple program that just loops over each row, updates candlesticks in memory map, and then dumps them once they are finished into stdout/file. It doesn't use any additional memory at all. I assume something like this should be possible with polars as well?
UPD code:
input_file = "input.csv"
output_file = "output.csv"
query = (
    pl.scan_csv(
        input_file,
        has_header=False,
        new_columns=[
            "label1",
            "timestamp",
            "price",
        ],
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("timestamp").cast(pl.Datetime).alias("parsed_timestamp"),
    )
    .group_by_dynamic("parsed_timestamp", every="1m", group_by=["label1"])
    .agg(
        pl.col("price").first().alias("open"),
        pl.col("price").max().alias("high"),
        pl.col("price").min().alias("low"),
        pl.col("price").last().alias("close"),
    )
    .select(
        [
            "parsed_timestamp",
            "label1",
            "open",
            "high",
            "low",
            "close",
        ]
    )
)
query.collect(streaming=True).write_csv(output_file)


Note: giving real code is better then just a plan: we may test it, or see other problems. In any case, I think you can do it in batches (see polars doc).

Thanks, updated with actual code. Will check batches

How can I make sure next batch doesn't contain points from previous batch? E.g I have aggregated data until 13:00 in a first batch, but the second batch also contains some points from 12:59 minute.

This almost certainly wants a real database so you can let it do the work.

Sad, my plan was to use polars to aggregate data and load it to the database, as database is slow and I needed to do some filtering.

What? Databases are lightning fast, they were literally made for doing these kind of tasks, with decades of optimization for that purpose =)

Yeah, but it's not the case of us. We also need to do some "smart" filtering of raw data which is not possible with current database.

It all depends on the database they use. If they use MySQL it may not be the best tool to perform that kind of query. Redshift or Snowflake are completely different.

You are collecting the result with .collect(streaming=True), by doing that, your LazyFrame becomes a dataframe, which is not streaming capable, and you write that dataframe to csv file.
If you want to use polars streaming capabilities, you need to use sink_csv() to write a LazyFrame to csv.
Also, I may be wrong but isn't group_by_dynamic() a window function ? If it's the case it may not be compatible with streaming.

Thanks. You are right, sink_csv returns an error for this query that it's "not yet supported".
